# Nginx location match regex not working

Tags: regex, nginx

I am unable to match location with below mentioned pattern, I want to set expires header to 24 hrs. but it is not working. It works if I just use below mentioned regex :

```
location ~* .*abc\.php.* {
expires 24h;
}
```

**Below example does not work.**

```
location ~* .*abc\.php.*xyz=detail.*login_something=.* {
expires 24h;
}
```

There is lot of content in between and after of "abc.php" & "xyz=detail" & "login_something=" so I have to use .* only.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anything from the `?` onwards is the query string and is not considered when matching the URI to a `location`. [Read this for more](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#simple_php_site_configuration).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : That does not work.

Comment: @KeyurM: Sure, read Richard's comment why.

Comment: @RichardSmith : Thanks for the info! Is there any work around to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you are trying to do, but the simplest method is to apply your mega regex to a variable that contains the entire URI (including the query string). This would be `$request_uri`

The second problem is how to manipulate `expires` and again, rather than use multiple blocks and have to reimplement PHP directives in each one, just use the `map` directive [as detailed in the `expires` documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires).

For example:

```
map $request_uri $expires {
    default                                   off;
    ~*abc\.php.*xyz=detail.*login_something=  24h;
}

server {
    ...
    expires $expires;
    ...
}
```