# Nginx - adding js css png jpg browser cache breaks the page

Tags: wordpress, caching, nginx

I am using Wordpress and when I add following, it breaks the page, it dont load any JS and CSS

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domain.com;
        client_max_body_size 20M;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_pass http://domainserver.com;
                proxy_connect_timeout       600;
                proxy_send_timeout          600;
                proxy_read_timeout          600;
                send_timeout                600;
                error_page 404 =301 /;
#               proxy_cache            STATIC;
#               proxy_cache_valid      200  1d;
#               proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_nocache $arg_nocache$arg_comment;
#               proxy_cache_use_stale  error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        }
        location /ads/ {
                proxy_pass http://domainserver.com;
                proxy_cache STATIC;
                proxy_cache_key "$proxy_host$uri$is_args$args";
                proxy_cache_valid 30d;
                proxy_cache_valid any 10s;
                proxy_cache_lock on;
                proxy_cache_use_stale error invalid_header timeout updating;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                expires 30d;
        }
#       location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
#               expires 30d;
#               add_header Pragma public;
#               add_header Cache-Control "public";
#       }
}
```

You can see the location block where I am trying to catch css|js etc

Comment: Is this commented code or uncommented?

Comment: Edit your question and add the entire `server` block. Also, look at your access log and error log and post any relevant entries. What is the document `root`, the URI that fails and the correct location of the files?

Comment: Yes @RichardSmith let me edit this question

Comment: @satys I commented this because it was not working

Comment: As requested, edited the question with complete server block

Comment: Location blocks are mutually exclusive. You need to implement a static root (if this server serves static content) or a proxy pass. However, rather than using a `location` block, [take a look at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40014605/nginx-location-match-regex-not-working/40018271#40018271).